# redis: Possible to update hash values with RedisJSON?

Tags: redis, redisjson

The documentation and Internet at large don't seem to provide any examples of setting values *into* a JSON object stored as a hash value, yet I know that the Redis collection types are often just hacks that allow their underlying storage to be managed similarly to scalar keys.

Can someone confirm whether RedisJSON supports this or doesn't, and, if it does, provide an example?

Thank you.

https://redis.io/commands/json.set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RedisJSON introduces a new JSON data type to Redis.

Therefor JSON.SET can only act on JSON types.

Comment: That's a good point (but still a shame). Thanks, Guy.

Comment: Please open a feature request https://github.com/RedisJSON/RedisJSON/issues